# Receive Notification of Battery State Change While in Background for iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, background, ios7, notifications

So I'm building an app for iOS 7 which needs to display an alert automatically when the phone is plugged in to charge, even if the app is in the background. 
The app also takes location into account, so I guess I can keep it receiving location updates. However, as far as I know, the app will stop receiving notifications about the battery state 10 minutes after it is put in the background.
Are there any suggestions as to how I can do this? I do not need to publish the app in the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable background fetch, and periodically check the battery state there. It's not as precise as you require, but this is the best you will get.